# What is important to you about becoming successful?

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-german

How the following sentence would be translated best?

> What is important to you about becoming successful?

Google translates it like so:

> Was ist Ihnen wichtig, um erfolgreich zu werden?

Is that correct? Somehow I doubt it, except I just don't understand the meaning of that question.

Comment: Please don’t use „code formatting“ unless absolutely necessary: it has not automatic line breaks and except for the first few words isn’t readable on mobile devices.

Comment: I think it is correct (not a native speaker).

Comment: Your translation means what does the person think needs to be done to become successful. But the english phrase asks why being successful is important for the person.

Answer (score 2):

People will understand the Google translation but sense it as an anglicism. Because

> Was ist ihnen wichtig?

is a fixed phrase meaning *What gives your life meaning?* It doesn't mix well with additional restrictions.

The typical way to ask for opinions in German use the verbs *finden* or *meinen/denken*. In addition, German speakers prefer snappy nouns before verb phrases.

> Was finden Sie wichtig für den persönlichen Erfolg?
>
> Was (meinen/denken Sie,) braucht es für persönlichen Erfolg?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! what do you think of that:
_Warum ist es dir wichtig Erfolg zu haben?_ For me it sounds the most meaningful until now. That makes sense to me

Comment: The English phrase sounded ambiguous to me. Yes, your translation attempt is correct apart from the missing comma in front of *Erfolg*.